# SectionedRecyclerView over Write first item

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview

I'm Trying to use : SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter , i have arrayList that have 30 elements with strings , i'm going to group every 10 elements with header Title ,
 first item should be "Item0" with header name "First 10 elements start" 
but when doing that i get :

"First 10 elements start"  // header titile

"Item1"  <---! note : it should "Item0"

so where is index number 0 gone?

```
 //adapter.addItem3(CategoriesList.get(0));
                List<SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section> sections =
                        new ArrayList<SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section>();

               sections.add(new SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section(0, "First 10 elements start"));


                //Add your adapter to the sectionAdapter
                SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section[] dummy = new SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.Section[sections.size()];
                SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter mSectionedAdapter = new
                        SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter(activity, R.layout.drawer_header_book, R.id.headerName, adapter);
                mSectionedAdapter.setSections(sections.toArray(dummy));
                mDrawerList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity));
                mDrawerList.setAdapter(mSectionedAdapter);
```

I'm using exactly as adapter  : 
https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/4c189fb1124df4556058

```
  public class DrawerItemCustomAdapterForAllBooks extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DrawerItemCustomAdapterForAllBooks.SimpleViewHolder> {

private final Context context;
Typeface custom_font;
ArrayList<Categories> mData;
private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
int BookID;

public void add(Categories s,int position) {
    position = position == -1 ? getItemCount()  : position;
    mData.add(position,s);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void remove(int position){
    if (position < getItemCount()  ) {
        mData.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}

public DrawerItemCustomAdapterForAllBooks(Context context, ArrayList<Categories> Categories2, int BookID) {
    this.mData = Categories2;
    this.context = context;
    this.BookID = BookID;
    custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/HelveticaNeueLTArabic-Light.ttf");

}

public SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listview_item_row, parent, false);
    return new SimpleViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SimpleViewHolder holder, final int position) {



    if (holder != null) {


        final Categories currentItem = getItem(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        SimpleViewHolder genericViewHolder = (SimpleViewHolder) holder;
        genericViewHolder.position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
        genericViewHolder.CategoryName.setText(currentItem.getName());
        genericViewHolder.CategoryName.setTypeface(custom_font);
        genericViewHolder.CategoryName.setTag(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        genericViewHolder.itemView.setTag(holder.getAdapterPosition());


        if (currentItem.getBookID() == 1) {
            genericViewHolder.CategoryName.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.nokhba_white));
            genericViewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.nokhba_darkrose));

            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.list_icon_e02)
                    .error(R.drawable.no_internet)
                    .tag(context)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.no_spic)
                    .into(genericViewHolder.CategoryImage);
        } else if (currentItem.getBookID() == 2) {
            genericViewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.nokhba_openrose));
            genericViewHolder.CategoryName.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.nokhba_darkrose));
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.list_icon_08)
                    .error(R.drawable.no_internet)
                    .tag(context)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.no_spic)
                    .into(genericViewHolder.CategoryImage);
        } else if (currentItem.getBookID() == 3) {
            genericViewHolder.CategoryName.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.nokhba_darkrose));
            genericViewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.nokhba_white));
            Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.list_icon_08)
                    .error(R.drawable.no_internet)
                    .tag(context)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.no_spic)
                    .into(genericViewHolder.CategoryImage);
        }
    }
  }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size()-2;
}

public Categories getItem(int position) {
    return mData.get(position-1);
}

public static class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected TextView CategoryName;
    protected ImageView CategoryImage;
    protected View itemView;
    int position = -1;

    public SimpleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.CategoryName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CategoryName);
        this.CategoryImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CategoryImage);
        //   CategoryName.setTypeface(custom_font);
        this.itemView = itemView;

        getAdapterPosition();

        this.CategoryName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CategoryName);
        this.CategoryImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CategoryImage);        }
 }

 }
```

Comment: Looks like line 5 doesn't account for the  `- "item1"` substitution. Could you add the code snippet for the drawer_header_book layout file?

Comment: Item1 is string object in Catagories arrayList , and "First 10 elements start" is header titile , it should print header then item0 then item1 so on , but it overlap item0 and prints header then item1 dirclty without item0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the library [SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter) you can group your items in sections and add a header to each section without worrying about the "position" of the headers:

```
class MySection extends StatelessSection {

    String title;
    List<Categories> list;

    public MySection(String title, List<Categories> list) {
        // call constructor with layout resources for this Section header, footer and items 
        super(R.layout.section_header, R.layout.section_item);

        this.title = title;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getContentItemsTotal() {
        return list.size(); // number of items of this section
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
        // return a custom instance of ViewHolder for the items of this section
        return new MyItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyItemViewHolder itemHolder = (MyItemViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your view here
        itemHolder.tvItem.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getHeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        return new SimpleHeaderViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        MyHeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (MyHeaderViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your header view here
        headerHolder.tvItem.setText(title);
    }
}
```

Then you set up the RecyclerView with your Sections:

```
// Create an instance of SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter 
SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();

// Create your sections with a sub list of data from mData
MySection data1Section = new MySection("First 10 elements start", categories1List);
MySection data2Section = new MySection("Elements from 10 to 20 start", categories2List);
MySection data3Section = new MySection("Elements from 20 to 30 start", categories3List);

// Add your Sections to the adapter
sectionAdapter.addSection(data1Section);
sectionAdapter.addSection(data2Section);
sectionAdapter.addSection(data3Section);

// Set up your RecyclerView with the SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```

Comment: thank you , i have did what you said , but Header come on first position of the  array not above it as i mention in my question , so my first item is "Item0" but header after header is created it take the 0 position and the getting item says "Item1" it should print "item0" then "item1" and so on, so my headers of section is actually taking the real position of my array items not grouping them

Comment: Are you sure your Category list has "item0"? 
Try to replace the "Categories"by "String" in MySection class above and create your sections with: 
new MySection("Header 0", Arrays.asList(new String[] {"Item0", "Item1", "Item2" }); 
You should see "Item0" as first element.